# Sourcing a file

Tags: linux, bash, source

I have a system wide install of a software . The source is located at /opt/Software . There is a bashrc file of the Software which is needed to be sourced for every user using it . 
Will the addition of

```
source $PATH_TO_SOFTWARE_BASHRC
```

to their ~/.bashrc
work for all users ? How should I set the permissions for the file at $PATH_TO_SOFTWARE_BASHRC so that all the users can access the software ?

Answer (score 5):

Just put that code in `/etc/bashrc` and every user will have it.
If there will be some permission issues, use chown/chmod to fix that.

Comment: I find no reference to `/etc/bashrc` in the Bash documentation.

Comment: There *is* the reference, check the `--rcfile` description. This filename may vary on various distributions. For Ubuntu it is `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

Comment: Actually, in the [original manual](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html) there's only a reference to `/etc/profile`. So apparently any other files in `/etc` are installation dependent, but the original docs don't say anything about this either.

Answer (score 0):

Set the permissions of the file to be world readable:

```
chmod 644 /path/to/your/file
```

Some shells don't understand the `source` command, so to make it work more broadly use:

```
. /path/to/your/file
```

even though it appears that you may only be using Bash.

Put that in each users' `~/.bashrc` or to make it simpler, put it in `/etc/bash.bashrc` so it's available to every user without having to maintain it in individual files.